# Can't login to new PostgreSQL server via pgadmin3 (on Fedora)

Tags: postgresql, fedora-25

I’m trying to install PostgreSQL on a Fedora 25.

I have edited postgresql.conf to include:

```
listen_addresses = '*'  
port = 5432
```

I have edited pg_hba.conf to include:

```
local   all all                         trust
local   all all 192.168.0.0/24          trust
local   all all 127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

Both can be seen as desperate, but I’m trying to get a connection.

I can access the PostgreSQL server via command line psql

But I can’t establish a connection via pgadmin3 – using the same login credentials.

I get the following message:

```
Ident authentication failed
The server doesn't accept the current user: The server reports 
FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres" 
If this message appears, the pg_hba.conf entry found for your client / user / database combination is set to "ident" authentication. Some distributions, e.g. Debian, have this by default. To perform ident based authentication successfully, you need additional setup; see the PostgreSQL help for this. For a beginner, it might be more appropriate to use a different authentication method; MD5 encrypted passwords are a good choice, which can be configured by an entry in pg_hba.conf like this: 
host all all 192.168.0.0/24 md5 
This example grants MD5 encrypted password access to all databases to all users on the private network 192.168.0.0/24. 
You can use the pg_hba.conf editor that is built into pgAdmin III to edit the pg_hba.conf configuration file. After changing pg_hba.conf, you need to trigger a server configuration reload using pg_ctl or by stopping and restarting the server process.
```

Can anybody see any obvious errors, or suggest possibilities I can try.

Comment: Your `pg_hba.conf` looks invalid. Rules for IP ranges should start with `host` rather than `local`. You also need to [reload the file](http://www.heatware.net/databases/postgresql-reload-config-without-restarting/); I'm guessing you missed this too, as doing so should have raised an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing, you can try with `pg_hba.conf` lines like this (the first line is for IPv4, the second one for IPv6):

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust
host all all ::0/0     trust
```

This allows all network connections to succeed without a password, so do *not* leave these lines in after testing.

Note that `pg_hba.conf` is processed from top to bottom, and the first matching line is used. So you want to put the lines at the very top.

After you have reloaded with `pg_ctl reload`, check the PostgreSQL log file if there were any errors in your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that. Still can't access though :-(

Answer (score 1):

After messing around some more...
My pg_hba.conf now is down to this:

```
# My desperate access - including a very open option...
local all all trust
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

The first two lines did not do it for me, but when I turned the last three
to all use 'trust', then I got the access - also through pgadmin3

Comment: If the `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 trust` line didn't do it and you needed to change the other three lines, the only explanation is that you attempted an IPv6 connection. I have extended my answer to cover that. Once you have verified that you can connect, change the `trust` to `md5` immediately to force password authentication. Then you can narrow down the netmask to allow only the required machines to connect.

Comment: I was not aware of using IPv6, but that must be the only logical explanation. Thanks for both your replies. I will turn to md5 (password) immediately, and I have found the exact ip#, and will narrow to that as well.